# How to update Django model Boolean field as true?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-models

I'm trying to update django model field, which consist boolean. Here's one user will apply for project & one field will be automatic false by default. after checking this insertion, the administration of the system will make the field true & approve the proposal. so, now i want to update the field as "True"

```
def project(request, project_id):
    all_primary_info = ProjectPrimaryInfo.objects.get(pk=project_id)
    if all_primary_info.approval == 'False':
        all_primary_info.approval.update(True)
    return render(request, 'administration/all_project_status.html')
```

This is the ProjectPrimaryInfo model:

```
class ProjectPrimaryInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    s_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    approval = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    p_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)  # project or thesis
    p_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    p_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    vision = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    charter = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.p_name
```

I expect the all_primary_info.approval will be "true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your view at this line

```
if all_primary_info.approval == 'False':
```

In your model you defined `approval` as a Boolean field, but in above line you used `'False'`, which is a String and NOT Bool because you enclosed it with single inverted commas. Effectively you are asking Django that
`if <Boolean Value> == <String Value>` which always evaluates to false and hence the code in `if` condition is not executed. To correct this you need to remove inverted commas around the `False`. So your above line of code should be

```
if all_primary_info.approval is False:

    # Do your stuff like this
    # all_primary_info.approval(True) is not correct. 
    # You can simply perform a .save on model instance to update the value

    all_primary_info.approval = True
    all_primary_info.save()
```

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: def project(request, project_id):
    all_primary_info = ProjectPrimaryInfo.objects.get(pk=project_id)
    if all_primary_info.approval is False:
        all_primary_info.approval(True)
    return render(request, 'administration/all_project_status.html')

but, it shows:

'bool' object is not callable in my browser & makes error.

Comment: You have done a minor mistake in updating the field. I have edited the answer to include correction of your mistake. Try it and see if you are now able to update it successfully.

Comment: I tried much but it showed me 'bool' object has no attribute 'update'

in browser. it's not working.

Comment: it works properly ! theres was an extra line in my code & made error ! Thank you !